# How to tail -f a file (or similar) for a specified interval?

Tags: unix, logging, intervals, tail

I am working on adding some nagios alerts to our system -- some of which will monitoring the rate of certain events hitting the nginx/apache logs (or parsing values from those logs.) The way I've approached the problem so far is with a simple shell script tail -f'ing the log for 25 seconds or so to a temporary file, killing the process, and then running awk, etc over the temp file. The goal here being to get a log "sample" over 25 seconds and then perform analysis.

This is less than ideal obviously because of the increase in disk IO due to these temp files -- what I really would like is an "enhanced" tail -f that would terminate the pipe cleanly after a certain number of seconds. Ie:

tail -f --interval '5 seconds' | grep "/serve"

Would tail the log for 5 seconds and show me all the lines that have "/serve".

I'd imagine I can whip up a ruby script to do this pretty quickly, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a more unixy way to accomplish this. At a high level, is there a better way to be taking samples of a log from the last N seconds (and no, I'd rather not be parsing timestamps, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach:

```
(tail -f /var/log/messages & P=$! ; sleep 5; kill -9 $P) | grep /serve
```

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. "apt-get install timeout" :)

Edit: Actually this kills tail, doesn't cause it to exit gracefully, so we lose the entire pipe. What I want to work is:

timeout -15 5 tail -f /mnt/log/nginx/nginx-access.log | grep '/javascripts' | wc -l

To tell me how many javascript files served in last 5 seconds, etc.

Comment: timeout -s15 5 tail -f /mnt/log/nginx/nginx-access.log | grep '/javascripts' | wc -l

Comment: When I run that, I just get "Terminated" and no output from wc - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that, as a Nagiios user myself, you do not want probe processes pausing for arbitrary amounts of time. That's going to, in the worst case, make Nagios check other things less often, or "clump" the checks.

What about a script that runs quickly (instantly) and parses the last few lines of the file, returning only interesting things with a timestamp later than a given time?

Answer (score 0):

GNU's `tail` has a `--pid` flag that can be used for this (`tail` will exit once a process with that PID no longer exists). Just start up a `sleep` process in the background and tell `tail` to exit when it does. Like so:

```bash
sleep 5 & tail --pid=$! -f /var/log/system.log
```

`tail` will exit with a `0` exit code when time is out.